# using listView and listAdaptor, list not getting displayed correctly

Tags: android, listadapter

I am trying listView and listAdaptor to populate a screen using database values. My list is not getting displayed correctly.
Below is the code from my DataBaseHandler class

```
  public List<Notifications> getNotificationList() {

        List<Notifications> notificationList = new ArrayList<Notifications>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS; 

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); 

        // looping through all rows and adding to list 
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
            do { 

                Notifications objN = cursorToNotifications(cursor);
                notificationList.add(objN);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
        } 

        // return contact list 
        return notificationList; 

    }
```

Here is how i print values calling above function

```
ArrayAdapter<Notifications> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Notifications>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objN);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

When i run the application it shows two entried, which is correct but displays in correct data. It shows something like

com.example.appname@41448fa0

com.example.appname@41449278

Can someone point me where i am going wrong.
Thank you

---

Sorry new to Android world. you mean add

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "something useful";  // define this
}
```

In my notification class, which is like

```
public class Notifications {

    //private variables 
    String _type; 
    String _message;
    String _id;

    // Empty constructor 
    public Notifications() {}

    // constructor 
    public Notifications(String type, String message, String id){ 
        this._type = type; 
        this._message = message; 
        this._id = id;
    } 

    // getting ID 
    public String getId(){ 
        return this._id; 
    } 

    public void setId(String id){ 
        this._id = id; 
    } 

    public String getType(){ 
        return this._type; 
    } 

    // setting id 
    public void setType(String type){ 
        this._type = type; 
    } 

    // getting name 
    public String getMessage(){ 
        return this._message; 
    } 

    // setting name 
    public void setMessage(String message){ 
        this._message = message; 
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "something useful";  // define this
    }
}
```

---

Sorry new to Android world. you mean add

```
@Override
  public String toString() {
     return "something useful";  // define this
  }
```

In my notification class, which is like

```
public class Notifications {

//private variables 
      String _type; 
String _message;
String _id;


     // Empty constructor 
     public Notifications(){ 

     } 
     // constructor 
    public Notifications(String type, String message, String id){ 
    this._type = type; 
    this._message = message; 
    this._id = id;

} 


// getting ID 
public String getId(){ 
    return this._id; 
} 

public void setId(String id){ 
    this._id = id; 
} 

public String getType(){ 
    return this._type; 
} 

// setting id 
public void setType(String type){ 
    this._type = type; 
} 

// getting name 
public String getMessage(){ 
    return this._message; 
} 

// setting name 
public void setMessage(String message){ 
    this._message = message; 
} 
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "something useful";  // define this
}
```

}

Do i need to make any other change anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you only need to override `toString()` in your Notifications class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "something useful";  // define this
}
```

---

Now that I've seen your code use:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return _message; //  + " (" + _id + ", " + type + ")";
}
```

Comment: I did not get what you mean by "override toString() in your Notifications class." My Notification has three strings only- notification ID, type and message. can you please explain little more. Thank you

Comment: ArrayAdapter calls the `toString()` method for each Object in its list, your output appears to be the generic `toString()` code. Incorporate the method above in Notifications to display a human readable String for each Notifications object.

Comment: toString() is a method inherited from Object.  By default, its prints out the Object id. You can override it in you Notifications class as he showed above. try this:                                    @Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getMessage();  // define this
}

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to generate `toString()` probs, Suppose you have model like that called `City`, for that you generate `toString()` as follows :

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City [name=" + name + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude="
              + longitude + "]";
    }
```

After generating my model looks like as follows :

```
public class City {
    private String name;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public City(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
         return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "City [name=" + name + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude="
              + longitude + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: But the loop already works, this is we mobiletest sees: "com.example.appname@41448fa0", "com.example.appname@41449278".